# Has "freak" always carried a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, etymology, connotation

Many words (such as *imbecile* and *idiot*) used to be technical terms or proper names, however, eventually came to be used mainly for insults, and are today considered negative.

Has the word *"freak"* always carried a negative connotation, or was it once a technical term for meaning "different" or "abnormal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't always carried a negative connotation, and even today, it doesn't always carry a negative connotation. Here are some examples:

You'll find an archaic definition where freak is a whimsical quality or disposition. ([ref](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freak)  #2)

Another archaic definition is to streak or fleck randomly. ([ref](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=freak))

A current definition, used in expressions like **health freak** means to be obsessed with something. So a health freak is obsessed with health ([ref](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091206074940AAbWHy7)). An **exercise freak** ([ref](http://www.tachmesmd.com/blog/avid-exercise-freak/)) is someone who is obsessed with exercise. Being obsessed is not necessarily a negative attribute.

I'll add this. Freak can also mean out of the ordinary ([ref](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freak) #2a and 2b). So a **freak storm** is a storm that is unexpected or out of the ordinary.

Comment: 'freak' is also increasingly used in Sports to describe a player with extreme athletic talent.

Answer (score 1):

Negative connotation to the extent that it implies 'abnormal'. *Different* is not negative, *Abnormal* is.

I hope this short answer will be helpful.

Comment: **Abnormal** is not negative. It just means not normal, or average. It can be abnormally bad, or abnormally good.

Comment: @Oldcat "typically in a way that is undesirable or worrying" (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abnormal) Usage!

Answer (score 0):

It usually has the bland meaning of "very different" and can really be used in a variety of situations as negative or positive.

Negative:
Holy cow that guy has 20 piercings.  What a freak!

Positive:
That guy weighs over 250 pounds and is the fastest person on the team.  What a freak!

Comment: The word is also used inanimately. We speak of 'freak weather conditions' etc.